# Reopen an app that is in Background when changing to another wifi network

Tags: ios

I have an app that needs to connect to another network while it's in background, then when I connect to the new network, reopen the app and open and specific view controller.

I don't have a problem opening the view controller but how can I reopen the app when I select a different network?

What can do so in can listen for the event and open again?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your app running in background forever, but can't reopen it selecting new network.

Comment: You can't really keep the app running in the background forever; it may be terminated due to memory pressure, it may be terminated by the user or the device may be turned off/restarted